# Replacing a phrase with a leading space in T-SQL - but it's also replacing the phrases without the leading space

Tags: t-sql

I've run into an interesting problem I'm hoping someone can shed some light on.

I'm trying to pull a unique list of names from an MS SQL Database - but the company has been sloppy with their names.  They were tacking on a code to the end of last name for some users.  I need to remove that code.

Example:
firstname     lastname

John          Doe

Mary          Smith AST

Mike          Jackson AST

Brian         Astor

Jackie        Masterson

In the example, "AST" is the code they tack on.  It's not tacked on to all last names either.  I need to get an output of just the last names without the code.

I would have expected this is a simple use of REPLACE.  I tried:

```
select REPLACE(lastname, ' AST', '') from table
```

Note the leading space in the quotes for the search phrase... this does work to remove the "AST" appended to the last names.

However - my problem is that it will also remove anywhere AST appears at the BEGINNING of the field.  So Brian Astor comes out as "Brian or"  since the field started with AST.  However... it correctly does not remove ast from the middle, so Jackie Masterson is fine.

Any ideas why it is ignoring the leading space in my search phrase for the beginning of the field?  I've tried ltrim to eliminate the possibility the field has leading spaces.

Thanks!

Comment: Uh oh.  I've got a confession to make.  As I was implementing casenonsensitive's suggest, I realized I'd made an error.

I was actually doing a replace on the combined phrase of two fields replace(firstname + ' ' + lastname, ' AST', '').  So of course it was finding ' AST' for the full phrase of 'Brian Astor.'   LOL.  I'm so dumb... it was a late night.  

When I changed it so the replace was truly just on the lastname field, the ' AST' by itself without the $$$ worked perfectly.  

Thanks for everyone's else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with an empty string will eliminate the searched string anywhere in your source string. So the behaviour is as expected.

If you only need to replace ' ast' at the end of your searched string, try something like this:

```
select replace(lastname + '$$$', ' AST$$$', '') from table
```

Of course you need to be sure that the `$$$` appended don't appear by chance in your source string (lastname). Which I guess is not that likely.

Comment: You will also need to use another Replace function to get rid of the "$$$" in the names that don't have "AST".

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(lastname + '$$$', ' AST$$$', ''), '$$$', '') FROM Table

Comment: Whoa.  That's kind of genius.  I'll try it.

Comment: @Reagan you might add something like `WHERE RIGHT(lastname, 4)=' AST'` to get only affected rows...